# Graphql Banana Cakepop OAUTH2 with Entra External ID

Tags: oauth-2.0, hotchocolate, microsoft-entra-id, microsoft-entra-external-id

I want to secure my backend API (REST+GraphQL) with Entra External ID (successor to B2C). Now, I cannot make Banana Cakepop work with active authn/authz. I have looked at [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oxgSk_Q-D3g) for guidance and edited the steps for my Entra External ID scenario. But after clicking `Fetch token` a new Banana Cakepop windows popus up with the following message amended in the URL:
[AADSTS40008 There was an unexpected error from the external identity provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/reference-error-codes#:%7E:text=a%20valid%20scope.-,AADSTS40008,-OAuth2IdPUnretryableServerError%20%2D%20There%27s%20an). I have checked the sign-in logs in Entra External ID, but have found nothing helpful.

##### In Banana Cakepop, the connection settings is configured as such:

Grant type `Authorization Code`

Authorization URL: `https://TENANTNAME.ciamlogin.com/TENANTID/oauth2/v2.0/authorize`

Access Token URL: `https://TENANTNAME.ciamlogin.com/TENANTID/oauth2/v2.0/token`

Client ID: `GUID_OF_THE_BANANA_CAKEPOP_APP_REGISTRATION`. Made a new app registration for the Banana Cakepop Client.

Client Secret: any

Use PKCE: `true`

Scope: `api://GUID_OF_API_APP_REGISTRATION/access_as_user`

Redirect URL: `https://localhost:7029/graphql/#/oauth` added in the app registration for the Banana Cakepop client application (`GUID_OF_THE_BANANA_CAKEPOP_APP_REGISTRATION`)

The scope is `api://GUID_OF_API_APP_REGISTRATION/access_as_user`. In the app registration, under `Expose an API`, I have added `GUID_OF_THE_BANANA_CAKEPOP_APP_REGISTRATION` under **Authorized client applications**, selecting the above scope

All else: `left blank or default`

---

Does anyone know what I need to do, to make it work? Any insights are feedback is/are greatly appreciated.

Comment: I configured the app and API in MS Entra ID. I did tests with Postman and I managed to successfully get token. I also tried to setup Banana Caekpop. Can you tell me which type of the app (single page/web) did you use in app registration tab?
All parameters you provided above are correct. I will try to help but need more details. One more question - do you use desktop version or web version of Banana?